# Long Tweets with Simple Intent in Android

Tags: java, android, twitter, android-intent, twitter4j

I want to post a long tweet (more than 140 chars) to twitter using just a simple intent in my android application. Here is what I am doing now:

```
    String strUrl = "http://twitter.com/home/?status=" + resultWords;
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse(strUrl));
    startActivity(intent);
```

resultWords is the long message i want to post as an update, but right now I am unable to because of the 140 chars limit. Is there a way that I can somehow post to twitter using the above method but include a portion of the text followed by a url link to the rest of the text such as "today I went to the market and http://bit.ly/2309"? What is the best and easiest way to handle this?

Also, if I must use a third party library like twitter4j, does it or are there any like it that support long tweets?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two major methods for sending tweets longer than 140 characters on Twitter.

The first, simpler method, is to simply break the message up into multiple tweets, possibly with "(cont.)" or similar appended to the end of each tweet. I trust you can figure out how to do this on your own.

The second is to use a secondary service that hosts the entire message, but then posting the start of the message and then a link to Twitter. A popular service is Twitlonger.
 They have an [API](http://www.twitlonger.com/api).

Comment: Thanks! I think I'll try the simpler method!